# Removing fluctuations from time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

How do I eliminate fluctuations in a binary time-series data in R?

e.g. this one is a graph of a time series data with fluctuations
 [image]

Now, if I down-sample or use SMA, the series becomes non-binary, and its hard to determine the exact points of the actual events.

In case the above sounds confusing, I'm looking for a way to change a series like 
`c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)` to 
`c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)`

Comment: You can use `rle` to find "bumps" in the data.

Comment: umm, not quite, especially cause the data described here is just a snippet of a much longer and repeating set, and these windows can be different in lengths. Perhaps I should be looking for event / change point detection?

Comment: With `rle`, you can find sequences that are out of line, no matter how long. The length can be defined by you. Example you gave, makes this trivial with `rle`. Unfortunately my crystal ball is not with me today, so I can't really predict what your data looks like. :)

Comment: hey, yeah it does work! with some SMA thrown in :P Can you make this an answer?

Comment: Why don't you publish a full answer of how you solved the problem?